# SharpSNMP: Using SNMP v3 with AES Privacy

Tags: vb.net, aes, snmp, sharp-snmp

I have configured 2 users on a SNMP v3 server (a Cisco router):

1. A user that uses DES as the privacy method (`desuser`)
2. A user that uses AES 128 as the privacy method (`aesuser`)

The privacy password and the authentication password for both the users were set to the same: `12345678` for testing purposes.

Using the code in the link below (at end of question), I was able to perform SNMP v3 queries using `DES` as the privacy method. For this I used the following command line args:

```
-v=3 -l=authPriv -a=MD5 -A=12345678 -x=DES -X=12345678 -u=desuser 10.10.10.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.1
```

The above worked without any issue.

I then tried to use `AES 128` as the privacy method by changing the privacy method and the user on the command line args as below:

```
-v=3 -l=authPriv -a=MD5 -A=12345678 -x=AES -X=12345678 -u=aesuser 10.10.10.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.1
```

This resulted in a TimeoutException:
[image: TimeoutException]

**I am able to use both these users (`aesuser` and `desuser`) on other SNMP agents without any issue.**

Please let me know:

1. What needs to be specified in the command line arg `-x` when using AES 128? Should it be just `AES` or `AES128`?
2. When I reviewed the code for `snmpget` (in the link at the end), I noticed that the value assigned to the command line arg `-x` is assigned to a variable called `privacy`. However, this variable is never used later in the code when setting the `IPrivacyProvider` object. The only two code paths available when setting the this object is `DESPrivacyProvider` and `DefaultPrivacyProvider`. (see code extract below) Shouldn't these be something like `AESPrivacyProvider` that would enable the AES privacy method on the code?

Code extract from the `snmpget` project's `Program.vb`:

```
    Dim priv As IPrivacyProvider
    If ((level And Levels.Privacy) = Levels.Privacy) Then
        priv = New AESPrivacyProvider(New OctetString(privPhrase), auth)
    Else
        priv = New DefaultPrivacyProvider(auth)
    End If
```

https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/blob/master/Samples/VB.NET/snmpget/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://help.sharpsnmp.com/html/T_Lextm_SharpSnmpLib_Security_AESPrivacyProvider.htm

As the documentation states, AES support is experimental.

You can write your own privacy provider to handle such algorithms, and it is purely a cryptography challenge and does not fall in #SNMP's scope (which only covers core SNMP features).